# How to add instance of javascript Class in a DOM element

Tags: javascript, class

I need to expose the istance of a class to be called from the dom element.

i've created a class that i'll instance as `new myCustomClass()`.
This class is related to a DOM element.

What i need to do in my class to access to his methods and property form the dom?

I need something like this (this is something that swiper.js do)

```
var foo = document.querySelector('.element-where-class-is-instanced').myCustomClass;
foo.init()
```

thanks to all

Comment: "*I need to expose [… on] the dom element.*" - really? Why? This is [usually considered a bad idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: @Bergi swiper.js do it, so i dont think this is so bad

Comment: It is. And you haven't explained what you think you need this for.

Comment: In certain situation I need to read some property o run some method of the Class that is related to that element. For example, re init the carousel with some different parameter. And I need to do this after the page is compiled

Comment: What do you mean by "*the page is compiled*"? And why can't you simply store the result of calling `new myCustomClass()` in a normal variable?

Comment: i mean when tha page il full loaded and all is rendered i can't access to the variable unless to create a global variable or store it in window. and i don't like it. 
Sometime i need to inject js code after the page is loaded and sometime not all variables are axposes. Storing it in the element property help me a lot

Comment: In that case, at least use a (global) [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as the property key, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the class instance to the element property earlier:

```
document.querySelector('.element-where-class-is-instanced').myCustomClass = new myCustomClass();
```